# Is it accurate to say that every program that responds to input has a main thread with an infinite loop?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, design-patterns, data-structures, responsive-design

I'm wondering if it's correct to say that every responsive program has at its heart a main thread like

```
while not quit
     if work to do
         do work
```

Example:

- HTTP listeners / web server
- User interface
- Service that executes jobs

Another way of phrasing my question:

Is it possible to create a program where no threads are executing until there is some type of stimuli (e.g. mouse click, network request)?

Comment: At least when working in assembly language, there is the concept of a hardware interrupt: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt

For instance, instead of wasting CPU cycles on a slow CPU checking if any buttons are pressed, you can trigger an electrical interrupt that stops the CPU and forces it to do what you want before resuming.

I'm not sure what the high-level equivalent is, but it probably exists.

Comment: Event-driven programming is the word you want here, I suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polling for input is (or should be) the exception rather than the rule. Your loop:

```
while not quit
    if work to do
        do work
```

Is a busy wait that keeps the processor busy polling for input.

The way most programs are written, the loop is slightly modified:

```
while not quit
    wait for input
    process input
```

That "wait for input" is a non-busy wait. The thread is in an alertable wait state, meaning that it doesn't consume any CPU resources. When an event that the thread has subscribed to occurs, the thread is woken up so that it can process the event. Then it goes back to sleep.

Note that "process the event" can and often does involve spinning up another thread.

So, yes: it is possible to create a program where no threads are executing until there is some type of stimuli. That's the norm for most applications these days, including HTTP listeners, GUI applications, and system services.